# Sublime Text 3 and Filter Lines plugin - need keyboard shortcut for Code Folding

Tags: sublimetext3

I have installed the [Filter Lines](https://github.com/davidpeckham/FilterLines) plugin (Windows OS) but I can't figure out if it is possible to have a keyboard combination for the `Edit` > `Code Folding` > `Fold With String` as I cannot find the default keyboard combination `ctrl+k` `ctrl+s` in the `Key Bindings - Default`?

If this is not possible, can anyone then refer to another filter plugin, which (ideally) realtime filters the text, so I can edit all the lines in one go?

I want keyboard shortcuts for the Code Folding lines:

[image: I want keyboard actions for the Code Folding stuff]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just look at [the plugin source](https://github.com/davidpeckham/FilterLines/blob/master/Filter%20Lines.py) and you will know what command to run as shortcut. If the name of the command class is `FoldToLinesCommand`, the command name in the shortcut files will be `fold_to_lines`.

Another solution is to open Sublime console, and enter

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

this will log all the commands in the console. After, you just have to run the command you want as a shortcut, look at the console output and write it in your key bindings files.
Do not forget to disable command logging when you are done to avoid useless output.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to extra plugins, I'm currently using Sublime's own folding shortcuts. Note that when making a selection, of a word or line for example, you will only fold the selected string.

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> shortcut may be used to fold a code block. 
Ofcourse, unfolding can be done with the related <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> shortcut.

These shortcuts are defined in the Default Sublime keymap, as `fold` and `unfold`, as following.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], "command": "fold" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+]"], "command": "unfold" },
```

Hope this helps you out.